# Can't get SQL Server CE to work with Visual Studio 2005 and Windows CE 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have been trying to make SQL Server CE work with Visual Studio 2005 for the past 4, 5 hours. but no luck. When I run my application I get the following error:

> Can't find PInvoke DLL 'sqlceme35.dll'

I have read countless threads and articles on it but unable to make it work. Using the following tools:

- Windows CE 5.0 device running Intel Bulverde processor
- Windows XP 32 bit with Visual Studio 2005
- SQL Server Compact 3.5

Here is what I did.

1. Created a new "Smart Device" project and selected "Windows CE 5.0"
2. Installed SQL Server Compact 3.5 (on Windows XP) which installed a bunch of folders and files
3. In my project I added a reference to "System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll" which is inside folder where SQL Server Compact 3.5 is installed
4. Then I wrote a few lines code as below which I copied from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134(v=sql.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

   ```
       SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = Test.sdf");
       engine.CreateDatabase();

       conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = Test.sdf");
       conn.Open();
   ```
5. Then I installed "sqlce.dev.ENU.wce5.x86.CAB", "sqlce.repl.wce5.x86.CAB" and "sqlce.wce5.x86.CAB" from "wce500\x86" on target device which created a bunch of DLL files in folder "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition"
6. Then I ran my program but I got error as described above. The error is being thrown by line **SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = Test.sdf");**
7. I thought may be I need to copy all DLLs from folder "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition" to my application folder on target device from where my program was running so I copied all files but still same error.
8. And then I thought may be I need to use "armv4i" instead of "x86" so I first installed "sqlce.wce5.armv4i.CAB", "sqlce.repl.wce5.armv4i.CAB", "sqlce.dev.ENU.wce5.armv4i.CAB" and as expected it didn't work. So I again copied all DLLs into my program folder but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Bulverde, IIRC, is the PXA27x series processor which is definitely an ARM core, not an x86, so you must use the ARM binaries.

Start by making sure you have a factory-reset device (the registry would be the important bit to reset).

Then use the CAB (or just the binaries directly) from this folder:

`%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\armv4i`

Make sure that the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` assembly is on the device (typically in your application folder).

If it still fails, you probably are missing a dependency.  Run depends.exe (on the desktop) against the SQL Compact binaries to see what they need and ensure those are on your target.

Comment: I ran depends.exe for "sqlceme35.dll" and it said 3 DLL files are missing. Plus I saw that for the CPU tab as shown in screenshot below, it is saying "x86" although  the "sqlceme35.dll" in question is from "armv4i" folder. So I guess it is showing this processor from the desktop?  http://i.imgur.com/nD87I.jpg

Comment: Yes, the important thing is to look at the DLLs and entries that it is looking for.  The processor architecture should still be correct though.

Comment: Here is screenshot of device that shows all DLL files including sqlcemeXX.dll are there with the application test.exe which I am developing. This time I tried with SQL CE 3.0 but same error. I have also tried 3.5 and 4.0. http://i.imgur.com/q1DC7.jpg